# Перестало работать разрыв тегов в PHP, после подключение MyAdmin и БД

Tags: php

Также перестали работать все мои проекты из-за этого. Прошу помочь

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdyS9.png

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я не могу например открыть цикл в одной php строке и закончить его на другом, на картинке вроде бы все видно.

Comment: Не знаю из чего это может быть, перестало работать как только я начал изучать БД, установил модуль MySQL, так же смотря видео гайды я добавил в проект .htaccess файл с значениями "AddDefaultCharset UTF-8". После этого перестало работать разрыв php кода

Comment: Попробуйте написать foreach как в [этом](https://github.com/ruslooob/web2lab/blob/master/public/views/screenshots.php#L24) примере.

Comment: Так как у вас работает, но не работает со скобками, мне кажется тут проблема с vcs так как она у меня выводит такую ошибку "Cannot validate since a PHP installation could not be found. Use the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable.", может ли это быть как-то связано? Вчера все проекты работали.

Comment: "Cannot validate since a PHP installation could not be found. Use the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable." означает, что у вас в настройках Code в строке php.validate.executablePath не указан путь до php.exe (ну или указан неправильный).